# Using a variable from a values file inside an xml attribute in the place of @id

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Is it possible to replace the `@id/blah` in a `View` (for example on `layout_below`) with a variable in a file, and then have two different files, one in each flavor that sets the `@id` according to the flavor built?

e.g.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    style="@style/badge_border"
    android:layout_below="@variable/test_name"
    tools:text="Exclusive"/>
```

then values/variables.xml

```
<variable name="test_name" value="@id/view1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, but why do you need to do that anyway? You can check for the flavor in your code and do different things as needed instead of changing the id based on the flavor. Or you can insert flavor-specific layout differences, such as different id (if you really want to change the id) to a common layout like:

```
<include layout="@layout/include_part_of_layout"/>
```

And then in res directory of each flavor have the same include file name but with different content like:

> flavor1/res/layout/include_part_of_layout.xml

```
....
<TextView
android:id="@+id/badge_for_flavor1"
style="@style/badge_border"
android:layout_below="@variable/test_name"
tools:text="Exclusive"/>
...
```

> flavor2/res/layout/include_part_of_layout.xml

```
....
<TextView
android:id="@+id/badge_for_flavor2"
style="@style/badge_border"
android:layout_below="@variable/test_name"
tools:text="Exclusive"/>
...
```

Comment: Yeah I know how to do two to diff layout files, my idea was that because the two layout files will contain exactly the same Views, but the only difference will be the ordering, then I could just change the layout_below values. I also don't really want to do this programmatically with if(flavor==vanilla) { blah} else if(flavor == chocolate){ blah} etc

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. Maybe if the layout differences can be taken care of by breaking the layout into several reusable sections and then for each flavor apply a different order of includes, as needed. Just a thought. Good luck!